# Selecting attributes from an object when using find() in MongoDB/Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So I'm new to Meteor, and have been playing around with it, but have hit a few issues with moving over to Mongo.

Below is a simple example, where I have inserted some documents into my collection, but cannot seem to extract the attributes properly.

**Here is my code (and my result vs expected result is below it)**

*vizart.js*

```
ContentPieces = new Mongo.Collection("content");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.loggedInDash.helpers({
    content: function () {
      return ContentPieces.find({});
    }

  });

}
```

*vizart.html*

```
<template name="loggedInDash">

    {{#if currentUser}}

        <p>Here is the content you've created</p>
        <ul>
            {{#each content}}
                <li>{{content}}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>

    {{/if}}

</template>
```

**Result (just pasted from the app in my browser)**

Here is the content you've created

- [object Object]
- [object Object]
- [object Object]

**Expected**

As you can see, I am not 100% sure how to pull out an attribute. For example, each document has a `name` attribute, and I'd like to spit that out in the list instead. Any help or guidance on how to select the `name` attribute from the `content` collection?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meteor template language ([spacebars](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md)) is inspired by [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). I'd recommend having a look at both sets of docs, but the handlebars documentation will get you up to speed with the basic syntax.

In your example, if each document in `ContentPieces` has a `name` then you can add it to your list like this:

```html
<ul>
  {{#each content}}
    <li>{{name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

I'd also recommend having a look at [this post](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/) to better understand template data contexts.

Answer (score 1):

In your process you are displaying the whole document, if you just want to display the name attribute you can do it by

```
 if (Meteor.isClient) {
 Template.loggedInDash.helpers({
 content: function () {
  var name=ContentPieces.find({}).name;
  if(name)
  return name;
   }
   });
```

You can just pass the field name that you want to display